# Retrain Random Forest with new Data

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I created a random forest

```
library(randomForest)
...
rf_default <- train(Species~., 
                      data=test, 
                      method='rf', #random forest
                      metric='Accuracy', 
                      tuneGrid=tunegrid, 
                      ntree=100,
                      trControl=control)

rf_default$finalModel
```

`rf_default$finalModel` contains now the model with the best parameters. Now, I would like to retrain the model with the best parameters with new data (something like `*.fit()` in `scikit`). How can I do that?

**EDIT**:

I followed the approach described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/training-on-the-full-dataset-after-cross-validation): I try to use the CV for finding the hyperparameters, and then, I want to use them to create a model on the complete training set

Comment: `rf_default$finalModel` is trained on the all of the data you provided as data argument. If this does not answer your question, then I am not sure if I understand why you would like using hyper parameters optimized on one data set to train a model on another data set?

Comment: I didn't know that - please add as answer so that I can check it

Comment: you can just use `predict(rf_default, new_data)` this way if you performed any preprocessing it will be performed on the new_data also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @missuse, `rf_default$finalModel` is just built over the whole dataset you put into `train`, regardless of the resampling method used.

```
library(caret)
train <- iris[ind,]
test <- iris[-ind,]
control <- trainControl(method = "cv",number = 10)
tunegrid <- expand.grid(mtry=2:(ncol(iris)-1))
rf_default <- train(Species~., 
                data=train, 
                method='rf', #random forest
                metric='Accuracy', 
                tuneGrid=tunegrid, 
                ntree=100,
                trControl=control)

rf_default$finalModel
#assessing the accuracy against the test set
confusionMatrix(predict(rf_default,test[,-5]),test$Species)
```

in the code above, `rf_default$finalModel` is trained on the entire dataset `train`.
If you want to fit another model on the whole iris dataset, using the best hyperparameter found in the previous model tuning you can do something like this:

```
rf_whole <- train(Species~., 
               data=iris, 
               method='rf', #random forest
               metric='Accuracy', 
               tuneGrid=rf_default$bestTune, 
               ntree=100,
               trControl=control)
```